# a better way to write TSQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wrote a query that is taking a long time to execute, 
the query is

```
SELECT 
  PD.POLICY_SID,
  CD.Coverage_SID, 
  AUD.Accounting_Unit_SID  
FROM POLICY_DIM PD
INNER JOIN  
  Current_Period_Coverage_Unpadded_Reserve_Fact CPCURF
  ON PD.POLICY_SID = CPCURF.POLICY_SID
INNER JOIN 
  Coverage_Dim CD
  ON CPCURF.Coverage_SID = CD.Coverage_SID
INNER JOIN 
  Accounting_Unit_Dim AUD
  ON CPCURF.Accounting_Unit_SID = AUD.Accounting_Unit_SID
where 
  CD.GL_Reinsurance_Class_Code = 1 AND
  CONVERT(INT,PD.GL_Legal_ID_BK) = 1 AND
  PD.US_SOE_Group_Code is not null AND
  Convert(INT,AUD.Par_Code_BK) = 4 ;
```

Now I don't have permission to look at execution plan for this query, I am just wondering is there another way to write similar query that can cost less time, please note all the necessary index are created in the database

Comment: "I don't have permission to look at the execution plan" - There's your problem right there. You could be missing indexes and table scanning, changing your SQL may not help at all. Find somebody who can show you the execution plan so you know what to fix. Trying to improve performance without knowing what isn't performing is a mistake.

Comment: Yes I think you are right, I have to talk with DBA for that

Comment: Doing the filtering without the CONVERT might speed things up, I guess they are strings? So do: `PD.GL_Legal_ID_BK = '1'`...
But impossible to really say without looking at the execution plan

Comment: Avoid the `Convert`, if it's string compare directly `='1'`

Comment: data is in string like 1,01,001,0001 that is why I used convert function

Comment: Comment out the `Convert` filter and see if the query runs faster, if not it does not matter.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Seems OP meant that it's '1' or '01' or '001', etc.

Comment: The convert discussion is academic since you're checking for equality; if it's stored as a string, testing  `PD.GL_Legal_ID_BK = '1'` is equivalent to checking whether `convert(int, PD.GL_Legal_ID_BK) = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, you can do some tweaking.
You can nest joins to join from something that was already limited by an inner inner join.

the syntax is something like that:

```
from x 
inner join y
  inner join z 
  on z.id=y.id
on x.id =y.id
```

you can also put

```
inner join ... on x.id = y.id and CD.GL_Reinsurance_Class_Code = 1
```

so the filtering will be performed during the join, so maybe on smaller amount of data.

You can also try to get rid of convert and compare to "1" to get rid of parsing string to int for every line of result.

And btw. remember about indexes. You need indexes to join fast.

Comment: I doubt this would create a different execution plan as the query optimizer should be able to optimize this.

Comment: @Magnus Doubt it all you want but I have seen better execution plans by bringing conditions into the join

Answer (score 0):

Some times you need to help the optimizer out
Too bad you cannot see the plan as I suspect it is going into loop joins

```
SELECT PD.POLICY_SID,
       CD.Coverage_SID, 
       AUD.Accounting_Unit_SID  
FROM POLICY_DIM PD
INNER JOIN Current_Period_Coverage_Unpadded_Reserve_Fact CPCURF
            ON PD.POLICY_SID = CPCURF.POLICY_SID 
           AND PD.US_SOE_Group_Code is not null
           AND CONVERT(INT, PD.GL_Legal_ID_BK) = 1 
INNER JOIN Coverage_Dim CD
            ON CD.Coverage_SID = CPCURF.Coverage_SID   
           AND CD.GL_Reinsurance_Class_Code = 1 
INNER JOIN Accounting_Unit_Dim AUD
            ON CPCURF.Accounting_Unit_SID = AUD.Accounting_Unit_SID 
           AND Convert(INT, AUD.Par_Code_BK) = 4 

OPTION (HASH JOIN);  -- try this but just guessing with a query plan
```

Comment: If it is doing loop joins on big sets it means the statistics are outdated. Rather run `sp_updatestats` then forcing a particular join type.

Comment: @Magnus Really you only get loop joins because of outdated statistics?  That is wrong.

Comment: Of course not, loop joins is the best choice for smaller sets. But if the query optimizer is choosing loop joins in very large sets it is because of outdated statistics on a non complex query like this one I would guess.

Comment: @Magnus I am not guessing.  I deal with large sets and joins a LOT.   Once you get up to 3 or more joins the optimized will go into a loop pretty often even with good statistics.

Comment: I do too, and I would advice against forcing a specific joint type except as a last resort. There is no way the optimizer would choose an incorrect join type for a query with 3 joins unless the statistics are messed up.

Comment: @Magnus Says you.   I don't agree.   I said try this - it will be faster or not.